# How to script resize export and specific folder output?

Tags: export, photoshop-scripting, script, actionscript

I maintain my uncle's photography website and that work currently at least consists of resizing new photos to different sizes (full, retina-thumbnail, regular thumbnail) and putting them on the site (non-wordpress).

To speed up my workflow, I was hoping to create a script (probably Photoshop, but any application will do) that

1. Scale the size to 1920 pixels width and export to folder ~/export/full/
2. Scale the size to 400 pixels width and export to folder ~/export/retinaThumb/
3. Scale the size to 200 pixels width and export to folder ~/export/thumb/

It's importing that quality, as well as file name is maintained, no matter what. My current Photoshop script forces me to set a specific file name and that should be a wildcard, i.e. remain the same as the inputs file name.

Thats why I'm hoping for a script that export and maintains filename, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Lucky for you Photoshop comes with a built in script to do just this!

We'll be using the **IMAGE PROCESSOR** script.

1. Navigate to `File -> Scripts -> Image Processor`

[image]

2. Choose your output folder

[image]

3. Enter your dimensions

[image]

4. Run the script

[image]

5. Double check the size of the images.
6. **OPTIONAL** Apply any other custom actions to the processing of the images.

[image]

Comment: Too bad I have to go through this -every- time, including for a single file. And I have to repeat those steps three times, since I need it in three different sizes. Image Processor for CC sucks, because I can remember the Batch functionality of CS6 was much better.. At least back then you had batch presets you could run on all open files with a single click, executing various commands.. This way I could record one action executing the export of all those three sizes. Update: Ah, I thought actions had gone, but they havent. :)

Comment: Well, as by writing that comment I found some suggestions for myself for Photoshop with help of the 'actions' option. Luckily actions/SaveforWeb has been updated so it doesn't include the file name, but does the folder now. That was my problem a year ago. Still looking for a AppleScript/Automator solution that utilises more of a drag&drop (put files in folder) solution, instead of having to open Photoshop. But heck, this saves me already a lot of time :)

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer If you don't want to open Photoshop every time, perhaps you could use ImageMagick?  [Here's](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/) an article on the subject pertaining to resizing images.  "mogrify" is the function that should interest you.